# Fixed point subalgebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras, group-actions

Suppose that $M$ is a von Neuman algebra and we have an action of a finite group $G$ on $M$. Denote by $M^{G}$ the fixed point subalgebra and suppose that $M^{G}=\mathbb{C}$ (i.e., we have an ergodic action of $G$ on $M$). Is there an elementary way to see why $M$ is finite dimensional? Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The conditional expectation $E$ of $M$ onto $M^G$ is given by $|G|^{-1}\sum_{g \in G}\sigma_g$. Hence one has $E(x) \geq |G|^{-1} x$ for every $x\geq0$. If $M^G=\mathbb{C}$, then there cannot be more than $|G|$ mutually orthogonal nonzero projections in $M$.

Comment: Thank you @NarutakaOZAWA. Can you please explain why this shows that the dimension is finite ? Thank you so much.